# HOW TO SET UP Proxy exception FOR ANDROID

Tags: android, exception, proxy, apn

i m developping an app that needs internet acces via Mobile data ,  but when i setup the proxy i have internet access but the intrenal (localhost) server doesn't work. so the is there any way to setup a proxy exception for android APN (3G or 4G) without root